# Open static file in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

I have a file stored in src/main/resources/data and I would like to open it from a Spring Bean class from one of my components. I wrote the following:

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "MyFile.csv";
private static final String SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");
private static final String FILE_FOLDER = "src" + SEPARATOR + "main" + SEPARATOR
 + "resources" + SEPARATOR + "data" + SEPARATOR;

private static final String FILE_PATH = FILE_FOLDER
        + FILE_NAME;


public boolean readFile() {

    String filePath = FILE_PATH;

    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);

    System.out.println(is);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // stuff
}
```

This class is a @Component, whose method is invoked by a @RestController.

With the given code, the InputStream is null. How can I find the resource cleanly? Thanks.

Comment: Checkout the ResourceUtils Spring package. Its full of really helpful static utility methods for accessing files without having to worry about separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directory `src/main/resources` is the base for your resources ("root of classpath").

try `filePath = "/data/MyFile.csv"`

note that you can safely use '/' on both windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

You should be opening the file as `InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/MyFile.cs")`.  This will work on all OSes (including Windows).  If you face problems (for example, inside WAR applications), you can try  the `InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/MyFile.cs")` variation.

Answer (score 1):

Using a more [Spring-like method](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/)

As it states on the page:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = 
       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"Spring-Customer.xml"});

    CustomerService cust = 
       (CustomerService)appContext.getBean("customerService");

    Resource resource = 
        cust.getResource("classpath:com/mkyong/common/testing.txt");
```

Then you can do:

```
      InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
      } 
      br.close();
```

And in your service class:

```
   public class CustomerService implements ResourceLoaderAware {

   private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    public Resource getResource(String location){
        return resourceLoader.getResource(location);
    }
```

}

Comment: Updated answer based on feedback

Comment: what is getResource in CustomerService?

Comment: It is just a method in a service class that would return an instance of org.springframework.core.io.Resource through a ResourceLoader.